# How to force Internet Explorer work in Internet Explorer 8 Document Mode?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, registry, internet-explorer-10, regedit

Currently i'm using this code in AutoIt:

```
RegWrite("HKU\" & $objAccountSID & "\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\", "AllSitesCompatibilityMode", "REG_DWORD", 1)
```

and forcing IE to open in compatibility mode.

But i couldn't found the registry entry for forcing IE to run in Internet Explorer 8 Document Mode permanently ->

[image: ie document mode]

There are few examples on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation) ([2](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieitprocurrentver/thread/f5ecfc0d-01e3-4d36-8608-406a6ec42aa9)) but none of them working so far.

Comment: Can I ask why it is you want to do this? If you have an application internally that requires this, simply send down the `x-ua-compatible` header instructing `IE=8`.

Comment: @JonathanSampson at this moment, i can not change html codes. sometimes why is not important.

Comment: You don't need to change HTML. If you can modify the response headers, you can send an `x-ua-compatible` header back with the data, and the browser will respect this.

Comment: @JonathanSampson i can only rely on registry settings at this point of course if there is available for this setting.